# How to track last login date for IBM Domino web user?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Does IBM Domino track the last login date for web users(UserName/Password and internet certificate)?  I know the access logs contains this information but wanted to know if there may be something built into Domino (maybe in Address Book).  Trying to come up with a method to disable web accounts that have not accessed a domino server in a specified time period.

Thanks,

Kev

Answer (score 1):

The User Activity area in the Database Properties picks up from the log.nsf, which is where this information is stored. But, typically, the log.nsf will only have a few days' worth of information. When I've had this requirement before, I've manually captured it via a custom login page or an `initUser` function I've had in applications.

Comment: Are you sure that 'User Activity' in the database properties logs browser logins? I don't think it does. A custom login page or a custom function that's triggered when a user signs in, is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solutions is to trigger an action from a live web page that generates a database.nsf?openagent event.

like:

or

Ideally you've use the openagent to print a content type and a response, but if you don't browsers do pretty well with invalid responses from servers.

inside your "myagent" you will have the users name available to you to write it to a document.

Your next challenge will be in getting the agent to trigger, but, not too often, ideally only on login.

When a user uses a custom login form it submits the username/password and redirection url in POST method.   You could change that to ...?openagent&nexturl=/blablabla.nsf

Your tiny little agent would run one and only one time upon login and update a document in a your custom logging database.

That's a developer's solution.

There are also admin solutions.  The server does keep track of active web sessions, but, it does not drop them into the log.nsf like it does upon session ending for a notes session.   I don't think it would be too much work from an admin standpoint to get that information there are a lot of event triggers available to you.  It's just been way too long since I worked on any server that anyone cared about statistics.

Comment: Unfortunately that would work for users with Username/Password.  Those that use internet certificates can bypass the typical login page in the domlog.nsf.   I may have to go the route of looking at access logs(text file) on a daily basis and parse out the authenticated names and compare to person docs to set a date field to know when last accessed.  I was hoping IBM had built some mechanism in there.  Especially for internet certificates.  Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: oh, that's easy.   If you are using domlog, then write an agent to read any new and modified documents.